# Uploading external web pages with limited rights

Tags: php, wordpress, doxygen

### Context:

We have a Wordpress website for our software. This software is not available to everyone. Moreover its users, according to their rights have access to different parts of the source code. In Wordpress we have created a role for each type of users.

We would like to make the doxygen documentation available for the users according to their role.

### Problem:

How can I upload the different folders of the documentation inside wordpress tree (each folder contains an index.html and other web files) in such a way that each user can only access the index.html of a folder if he has a role that allows it.

### My solultion:

For now, all I can do is to put the folders outside the wordpress file structure and put links in wordpress pages (that have limited rights) toward those external pages.

### Why my solution is bad:

If you know the exact link to some external file, you can access it without even being logged in wordpress.

Can you please suggest a better solution ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to give the people opportunity to access a file different that the webserver can interpret for you, you will need to make file system rights, and users in the operating system that will interact with this rights.

However, it's bad solution to have the files in public folders that can be accessed directly by the public.

You have two options:

- If these are .php files (or whatever the webserver can interpret), you can put logic in them to determine the user rights
- If these are not .php files (i.e. .exe, .doc, .pdf etc...), don't put them in public folder. Put them somewhere that they cannot be accessed by the public and with .php script interact with them. Generate a token that is valid only for this session to determine file interaction access and use `readfile()` or any other function which can stream them to the endpoint.

Comment: The users only have roles through their registration in the wordpress website. They have no accounts on the server. So file system rights is not a possibility for us. 

I am pretty sure there is a way to upload the documentation in such a way that it is recognized by wordpress, and hence giving us the possibilty to affect access rights from wordpress.

Thanks for your help anyway.